# Trying to remember a movie: Brother and sister with special powers, including restoration

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie in the 90s when I was young. It is *not* *Escape from Witch Mountain*.  I would recognize the face of the actors if I saw a pic.

Plot is fuzzy, but I believe it had the following:

- Brother/Sister
- Special powers of some kind, mostly mind based
- One power they had was to restore damage.
- They had a friend, old asian guy and a green car, his car was basically damaged and the boy used his power to restore the car to new.

What is this movie?

Comment: I remember that movie... for a bit, I was thinking Pat Morita, but that doesn't quite match up with the film list. He wore a brown hat and I can hear his voice in my head.

Comment: The footage of the car fixing itself is in my head too...

Comment: A scene like this occurs in Ben 10: Alien Force

Comment: A scene like this occurs in Christine - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I98L5imvTh4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like *[Return From Witch Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_from_Witch_Mountain)*, actually.  Naturally, it has the brother and sister with psychic powers.  There was also a friendly Asian character, played by [Jack Soo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Soo), who drives a green van, which Tony/Tia use their powers to repair.

[image]

Comment: I'm intrigued why you edited out the info about the accident

Comment: @Valorum As I recall, the accident was a collision with a fire hydrant.  That video clip doesn't look like the damage from that kind of accident.  That looks more like the van was a decayed heap of junk, and was returned to working order from that condition.

Comment: The van was a junker before the accident and a *broken* junker afterwards. The kids restored it to mint.

Comment: Yup, that is the one.  Dang.  I looked at return from which mountain and the characters seemed different.  But that was exactly the scene!!  THanks guys!!