# Movie identification: twins (aliens) with telekinetic lockpicking powers fleeing to meet their people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, telekinesis

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238153/looking-for-movie-with-telekinetic-lockpicking) sparked a memory of a different movie. The main thing I remember is that there was a <s>pair of girls</s> pair of siblings (twins, I think) who for the most part of the movie were fleeing from someone to somewhere. They had minor superpowers. One of them was definitely opening locks and starting machinery with telekinesis. I remember that they helped out and started someone's car like that. In the end they met some other people and it was revealed that the <s>girls</s> siblings are actually aliens. Possibly they met their family? Then they took off in their spaceship (it was a happy ending). The whole thing was a children's movie, not horror or thriller or anything like that.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - No. Please read my question.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix we don't duplicate story-id until we've had confirmations that the stories are indeed the same with acceptances from the OPs

Comment: Could it have been [*Escape to Witch Mountain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_(1975_film))? That was a boy and a girl, and I don't remember any lock picking specifically but they did have minor powers including telekinesis, and they did turn out to be aliens.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - You know, that could be it! Please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix you shouldn't be flagging questions as duplicates unless both questions both have the same story identified and both are accepted (in some form, be it officially or with a comment etc.) by the respective OPs. It's a [policy of the site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067).

Comment: Would it be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150219/trying-to-remember-a-movie-brother-and-sister-with-special-powers-including-re?noredirect=1&lq=1? It sounds like that one only covers the second film.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Hmm, no, it's definitely not the sequel. The first one sounds much more like it. But nice to know there _is_ a sequel. :)

Comment: I edited the question to remove the "two girls" part. That might mislead someone.

Comment: Interesting, I checked out the other sequels and reboots, of which there seems to be a few. Didn't know this was such a popular movie! :) I still think the 1975 original is what I had in mind, although the phrase I read in the synopsis of the 1995 reboot which states "a world where everyone has a twin" also tickles the back of my mind. Guess I'll have to watch them to see. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is most likely *[Escape to Witch Mountain](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072951/)* (1975); the only thing that doesn't match the question is that the two alien siblings are a boy and a girl.  The film, which was a favorite of mine when I was young, was based on the 1968 novel by [Alexander Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Key) (probably best known as the author of another children's novel about an alien with psychic powers who is trapped on Earth, *The Forgotten Door*).  It was followed up with [a sequel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150219/trying-to-remember-a-movie-brother-and-sister-with-special-powers-including-re/) and a feature-length pilot for a series (with different actors, since the Kim Richards and Ike Eisenmann had grown too old to play the main characters).

From the plot summary, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_(1975_film)):

> The movie centers upon the brother and sister pair Tony and Tia, whose surname they initially know only as that of their deceased adoptive parents, Malone. The children are placed in an orphanage, where they face difficulties stemming from their strange psychic/psionic abilities: Tony can psychokinetically move and control inanimate objects with the aid of his harmonica, while Tia can communicate telepathically to Tony, commune empathically with animals, and experience premonitions. Tia also possesses minor telekinetic abilities. She carries a "star case" with her at all times, which eventually reveals a strange map.
>
> ...
>
> During a field trip to see a movie, Tia experiences a premonition and warns wealthy attorney Lucas Deranian against a potentially dangerous accident. Deranian informs his employer, millionaire Aristotle Bolt, of the children's unique abilities. Bolt, obsessed with the paranormal, demands that Deranian retrieve the children at all costs. Deranian's detective work leads him to the orphanage, where he poses as Tia and Tony's uncle, though not under the name Bené, and takes them to Bolt's mansion.
>
> Though initially suspicious of Bolt's motives, Tia and Tony are lured in by the wealthy trappings of Bolt's home. Bolt eventually reveals that he has been monitoring the children via a closed-circuit television system and that he and Deranian are fully aware of their unusual powers. The night of this revelation, Tia and Tony make an escape, using their abilities to psionically control a wild mustang, guard dogs, and the security fence, as well as using Winkie, Tia's cat, to make the allergic security guard let them pass.
>
> ...
>
> As their memories begin to fully return, the children realize their accident at sea did not involve a boat but a spacecraft. Tony and Tia are actually of extraterrestrial origin; the double star emblem on the star case stands for a binary star system where their home planet was located.
>
> Having come to Earth because their own planet was dying, survivors of the journey made their way to Witch Mountain and formed a community to await the surviving children, each pair in possession of a star case to help them find their way to their new home. Tony and Tia are the first to reach their destination. The children are reunited with their Uncle Bené (who survived after all, thanks to an "accommodating" shark whom he'd telepathically asked for help) and board another spacecraft.

Here are the two protagonists, along with Donald Pleasance as Deranian.
[image: Tia, Tony, and Deranian]

Comment: As soon as I read the title, I was thinking of the same movie. (Despite, as you say, the fact that the child co-stars weren't both girls.) I wasn't surprised to click in for a closer look and see that someone had beaten me to it.

Comment: Also another remake (which many people would prefer not to talk about), *Race to Witch Mountain*. :-D I loved those movies as a kid... we had them on VHS, taped from Disney Channel Movie nights, and a promotional VHS that my brother got for Christmas (to this day, I don't know if my grandparents thought it was multiple films on one tape, or knew it was a promotional) that had clips from it as many as a ton of other Disney movies.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Besides the 2009 version with The Rock, there is apparently another 1995 remake, which I had not even heard of until recently.

Comment: And the two original child actors apparently made a short parody film, *The Blair Witch Mountain Project* in 2002.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that I've never seen this movie in its entirety (or much of it at all), yet it was exactly what I thought as I started reading the question. I guess that psionic control still works after all these years...